# Security and Permissions Requirements for VS Code

Tags: security, visual-studio-code, file-permissions, folder-permissions

I am in a government organization and thus a pretty locked-down environment.  I can get VS Code and extensions, but I have to fill out a form for requirements and justification.  I have the justification down and I have a good handle on the technical requirements, but I am not sure of what security/permission exceptions to open or grant.  For example, I cannot even write to my temp folder.  If I wanted to do so I would need to make a request and justify it.  Well, this request is much more complicated and detailed than granting read/write on my temp folder.  My question is, what local permissions, open ports, and execution of libraries would I need to request?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to install VS Code in its [portable mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable). Then it should(!) not need any other directories to write on besides the default temp dir - which you can also put into the vs code install directory.

To enable portable mode:

1. Download a zip package of VS code
2. Extract to a folder
3. Inside that folder create a directory named data

To add the tmp dir:

4. Inside the newly created data folder create a directory named tmp